# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \subsetneqq\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> We want to show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \subsetneqq \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$.

***Answer:*** We know that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is the smallest integral domain which containts $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\sqrt{2}\}$ & $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$ is the smallest integral domain which containts $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\}$. So, for $``\subseteq"$, we have to proove that $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$.

It's clear that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$.

I have seen in a book that $$-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]\ \ (*)$$ and I don't understand why this happens. Could you explain this please?

If this is valid, then we can see that 
$\sqrt{2}=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})-\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})\in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$
and we are done.

Now for $``\neq".$ We suppose that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. We know that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space and $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$ is one base. So, $$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=\langle 1,\sqrt{2} \rangle \iff \exists \ a,b \in \mathbb{Q}:\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=a+b\sqrt2.$$ 
We have the cases: If $a=b=0$, then $\sqrt{2}=-\sqrt{3}$, contradiction. If $a=0,b\neq0$, then $b=\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}} \notin \mathbb{Q}$,  contradiction. If $b=0,a\neq0$, then $a=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}$,  contradiction. If $ab\neq0$, then $\sqrt{3}=a+(b-1)\sqrt{2}\implies3=a^2+2a(b-1)\sqrt{2}+2(b-1)^2$. If $b=1$ then $a=\pm \sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}$, contradiction. If $b\neq1$, then $\frac{3-a^2-2(b-1)^2}{2a(b-1)}=\sqrt{2}$, contradiction. So, $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, and finally $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] \subsetneqq \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$.

*I would like to explain me the $(*)$ relation and check the other part. Any other way is welcome.
Thank you in advance.*

Comment: (*) Is true because $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ for $a=\sqrt{3},b=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Right--just multiply both sides by the denominator.

Comment: Why dislike????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea using your own work: you've already shown that $\;-\sqrt2+\sqrt3\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)\;$ , so we also get that

$$2\sqrt3=(-\sqrt2+\sqrt3)+(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)\implies \sqrt3\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$$

Thus, if $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)\;$ , then $\;\sqrt3\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\;$ , but then

$$\sqrt3=a+b\sqrt2\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb Q\implies 3=a^2+2b^2+2ab\sqrt2\implies$$

$$\sqrt2=\frac{3-a^2-2b^2}{2ab}\in\Bbb Q\;,\;\;\text{ contradiction}$$

I leave to you to check in the above the easy cases when $\;a=0\;$ or $\;b=0\;$ .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nice proof. Could you please write me down why $-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} \in \Bbb{Q} [\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$?

Comment: @Chris, you already did it! $$(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)=3-2=1\implies \sqrt3-\sqrt2=\frac1{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$$ the last inclusion being true because $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)\;$ is **a field** and thus it contains the multiplicative inverse of all its non-zero elements.

Comment: Is there another explanation without using that $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$? In other words your observation that $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$ is a field?

Comment: @Chris I doubt it but perhaps, yet why would we want to avoid such a nice, elementary fact as that??

Comment: Your question is good, but I try to find an explanation without this, because the book I found it doesn't write someting for the property that this is a field.

Comment: How can we proove that $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]$ is a field? Is there a way with the definition?

Comment: Chris, you can try this (any decente algebra or Fields extensions or Galois Theory book shall have it): if $\;F\;$ is a field and $\;a\;$ is an element in some superfield of $\;F\;\;$,  the ring $$F[a]:=\left\{\,f(a)\;/\;f(x)\in F[x]\,\right\}\;$$ is *a field* iff $\;a\;$ is algebraic over $\;F\;$ , and in this case we have the equality $\;F[a]=F(a)\;$ , where the right side is the field of rational functions in $\;a\;$ .